# JavaScript: Group data from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js

I have an multidimensional array and want to filter it based on the value at a particular index value. It looks like this:

```js
arr = [
       [1 , 101 , 'New post ', 0],
       [2 , 101 , 'New Post' , 1],
       [3 , 102 , 'another post' ,0],
       [4 , 101 , 'New post' ,1],
       [5 , 102 , 'another post' , 1],
       [6 , 103 , 'third post' ,1]
]
```

I want to filter this array based on postId and get the sum of titles with the same name. The result would look like this:

```js
result_arr = [
       [101 , 'New post', 2],
       [102 , 'another post' ,1],
       [103 , 'third post' ,1]
]
```

Comment: are you doing it in a `nodejs`? what is the version of `nodejs` you are using? I may have a better solution for your problem

Comment: No i am not doing node.js ..i am using this in d3js and getting this type of data from excel file .

Comment: ok, then added an answer for you, check please @Mayank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty brute force method, but it certainly works. By the way, I would merge your items by id, rather than title, since in your sample your title casings are mismatched.

```
var merged = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!merged[arr[i][1]]) {
        merged[arr[i][1]] = {likes: arr[i][3], id: arr[i][1], title: arr[i][2]};
    } else {
        merged[arr[i][1]].likes += arr[i][3];
    }
}
var result_arr = [];
for (var post in merged) {
    var p = merged[post];
    result_arr.push([p.id, p.title, p.likes]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, using `reduce` to create the groups, and then spread them back to array.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 101, 'New post ', 0],
  [2, 101, 'New Post', 1],
  [3, 102, 'another post', 0],
  [4, 101, 'New post', 1],
  [5, 102, 'another post', 1],
  [6, 103, 'third post', 1]
];


const groups = arr.reduce((groups, current) => {
  if (groups[current[1]]) {
    groups[current[1]][2] += current[3];
  } else {
    groups[current[1]] = current.slice(1);
  }
  return groups;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(groups).map((key) => groups[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the array, and use an object as map for each post as using the post id as key. If the any object is found using the key in the map, add post value, otherwise add a entry for the post id from the input array. Here we go:

```js
var array = [
    [1, 101, 'New post ', 0],
    [2, 101, 'New Post', 1],
    [3, 102, 'another post', 0],
    [4, 101, 'New post', 1],
    [5, 102, 'another post', 1],
    [6, 103, 'third post', 1]
];

function mergeArray(array) {
    var o = array.reduce(function(init, each) {
        var ex = init[each[1]];
        if (ex) {
            ex[2] += each[3];
        } else {init[each[1]] = each.slice(1);}
        return init;
    }, {});
    return Object.values(o);
}

console.log('Result: ', mergeArray(array));
```